# ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!)! is always null

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, navigator

I want to navigate back when a push notification comes and there if certain current route

[Try on Zapp](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zo6062co706?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart:0-2322)

[Get more detail on the issue open on Flutter Github repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133925)

Comment: Don't you have access to the current "BuildContext" of your build tree? Are you using any type of library that prevents your to get the current BuildContext?

Comment: No I don't use any library the usecase is that I want to know the current route when a push notification arrives from firebase and if app on certain route then I want to navigate back but the problem is that from regular widget tree context I cant use that in firebase on tap handler thats why I try navigator key context also the navigator key context is not null that modal route from that content is always null